# Javascript Delaying with setTimeout for a function that uses SetInterval

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an animation that works - `showAlert` that is called in body `onload`. Now I want to delay the animation for some time (1 second in the code snippet) using `setTimeout`.

I call `delayShow()` in body `onload`.

```
function delayShow() {
    var runOnce = setTimeout(showAlert, 1000);
}

function showAlert() {
    var e = window.event;
    var element = e.target;

    var alert = document.getElementById("hide-navigation-instruction");

    var opacity = 0.0;

    function fadeIn() {
        opacity += 0.03;

        alert.style.opacity = opacity;

        if (opacity >= 1){
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }

    var id = setInterval(fadeIn, 5);
}
```

The code does not work. If I change `setTimeout` to `setTimeout(function(){alert("hello")}, 1000)`, it will work.

Anything I could do to set the delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have the lines

```
var e = window.event;
var element = e.target;
```

This is not the way to use events. Either do further research on this topic or ask a specific new question about events in the context you want to use them.

The two lines above produce errors. Finding the developer tools option within your browser will allow you to switch on the console which will show you the errors.

The following code works although the delay of 5 milliseconds in setInterval is too fast to be noticeable as a fade in.

```
function delayShow() {
    /*added line below to ensure hide-navigation-instruction is hidden
      at start. You may have already set this within css style */
    document.getElementById("hide-navigation-instruction").style.opacity=0;
    var runOnce = setTimeout(showAlert, 1000);

}

function showAlert() {

    var alert = document.getElementById("hide-navigation-instruction");

    var opacity = 0.0;

    function fadeIn() {
        opacity += 0.03;

        alert.style.opacity = opacity;

        if (opacity >= 1){
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }

    var id = setInterval(fadeIn, 5);
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! I was reusing some code and did not realize I do not need event.